# Eclipselink Shared Cache - Lazy associations

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I'm devoloping an application using JPA eclipselink 2.6.4.

I'm enabling the shared cache for serveral JPA entities.

```
@Entity
@Cache(
      type=CacheType.SOFT,
      size=500 
    )
public class Tutor
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  ... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Cache(
      type=CacheType.SOFT,
      size=500 
    )
public class Student
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="TUTOR_ID")
  private Tutor tutor;

  ... getters and setters
}
```

I got a typical entity association of tutor and students. It is defined as LAZY because we want to avoid the "N + 1 problem" when a students query is done.

When we execute a students query and we want the association to be resolved, we use JOIN FETCH technique:

```
SELECT s FROM Student s JOIN FETCH s.tutor t WHERE s.id = :id
```

Up here all right.

The first time we execute the JPA query, because shared cache has no students yet, a database query is executed. We get the student entity populated with the tutor entity.

Nevertheless, the second time we execute the same query, there is a hit in the shared cache, so a database query is NOT executed. But then the student entity IS NOT populated with the tutor entity.

We would like to get the student entity populated with the tutor entity.

We have seen that this is possible changing the association to EAGER, but we don't want to change to EAGER to avoid "N + 1 problem".

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to force the query and bypass the cache, use a refresh query hint.  If it is in the cache already though, there isn't a point in forcing a fetch join query over both tables - now you only need a query for the tutor, and only if it isn't also there in the cache. You can just access tutor on the returned student to ensure it gets fetched immediately using a query just for the tutor, or try using an EclipeLink fetch query hint and see if it forces EclipseLink to do it for you - https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#FETCH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to bypass the shared cache. What I really would like is to get the main entity populated with the "manyToOne" association from the "shared cache". When I execute the query I'm getting the main entity without the "manyToOne" association, and I've to call the getter (getTutor method) to populate the student with the tutor (that is in the shared cache too).

Comment: Refresh forces reloading what is in the shared cache with the current query options. But yes, if you don't want a query on the Student table when it is already in the shared cache -don't. Use your query as is, and force the getTutor method to ensure it gets loaded immediately - you will at most have 1 query. Try using a load group and you can force EclipseLink to fetch what you want.

Comment: Thanks again, Chris! I don't need a "load group" because I'm using a "join fetch" in the JPA query. Thanks to the "join fetch", the first time I execute the JPA query, the student entity is populated right (with the tutor), and the shared cache is filled with the student. But in next executions of the same JPA query, the student comes from the shared cache, but with a null reference to the tutor. I have seen that I have to execute the getter method if I want to get the tutor association populated. What I'm looking for is to get the tutor without executing the getter method

Comment: You need a load group because your query is getting something from the shared cache, so join fetch isn't used - it is a database query option, not a shared cache query option. As for not using the get accessors - you should. JPA requires you to use method access, allowing providers to add byte code enhancements. Every time the object is read from the shared cache into an empty EntityManager, its lazy relationships will be blanked out - this is an intentional optimization to avoid having to process objects for change detection.